# How to replace a localstorage item with a new one

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage

we try to set a new item in the localstorage. But only if its higher then the last item. Our problem is that the if comparison doesnt work. Any ideas?

Sorry if we are asking a stupid question but we´re just beginners looking for help. Thanks a lot.

```
 saveList(){

 let newScore:any; //this is a numeric value pushed from another page
 newScore=this.newlist;


 localStorage.setItem("scores", (newScore));

 parseInt(localStorage.getItem( "score")) ;


 let highscore= parseInt( localStorage.getItem("scores"));



 if(newScore>highscore){ 

  localStorage.setItem("scores", (newScore));


}

  //let storedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scores"));   
}
```

Comment: The way I see this logic... `newScore === highscore`. You set `newScore` to localStorage, and retrieved it and set it to `highscore`. It is always going to be the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since localStorage.getItem() will return null if there is no object in local storage you can do use this

```
saveList(){

 let newScore:any;  
 newScore=this.newlist;

 let highscore= parseInt( localStorage.getItem("scores")); 

 if(  highscore > newScore ){
  // do nothing 
 } else  { 
    localStorage.setItem("scores", (newScore));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operation

```
saveList(){
    let newScore=this.newlist;
    let highscore= parseInt( localStorage.getItem("scores")); 
    localStorage.setItem("scores", ((newScore>highscore) ? newScore : highscore));
}
```

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider replacing the local item by using the same key, like this...

```
var boo = "my boo"
var newBoo = "my new boo"

localStorage.setItem("foo", boo);        // foo: "my boo"

// replacing...
localStorage.setItem("foo", newBoo);     // foo: "my new boo"
```